# What happens on write() fail?

Tags: c, linux

If I'm writing a single character to STDOUT 1MB times in a loop, when the system has 128KB both RAM and disk size.

```
char c = 'c';
for (int i = 0; i < 1024*1024*1024; i++)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
```

At a certain point, write will fail, right?
Will the program terminate? Will it continue with write() returning -1's?

Comment: @Barmar it could be 128k flash size on an  embedded device.

Comment: @Barmar I wrote small sizes just for the example

Comment: Why should it fail? Is your stdout buffered somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what happens with your program output and on a few things with the environment itself.

In isolation - nothing interesting will happen, you'll print out 1GB of `c`s which will be consumed by something attached to the output (for example a terminal). That output will start dropping the old lines of text from its scrollback buffer and keep memory usage more or less constant.

If the output is redirected to something that tries to buffer all your output, it's going to run out of memory at some point and get killed by OOM-killer. At that point your app will get a `SIGPIPE` signal and crash (unless you have a handler).

Alternatively your output could be blocked by the receiving end which knows it's running out of storage. Then your return value is `-1` with errno specifying exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're redirecting the output of the program to a file on the small disk.

The program won't terminate. When `write()` fails it returns `-1` and sets `errno` to the reason for the failure (probably `ENOSPC`). If you don't check the return value, you'll just keep looping and nothing nore will be written.

Comment: I'm not even sure that `write` will fail. They don't seem flash/RAM consuming operations. che character 'c' will be simply shown on stdout.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I updated the answer to say that it assumes the output is redirected to the device.